# Coordinating singleton token between AWS Lambda instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Consider a chat bot written as an AWS Lambda function. It gets invoked via HTTP requests from a 3rd party service, the chat service into which it is integrated. Now, that 3rd party API is a bit… quirky. The main issue with it is: it requires an authentication token to interact with, **but only one token can exist at any one time.** The way it works is:

- Bot creates a request to `POST /auth` with a bunch of secret information, and gets returned a token in response.
- Bot then makes a request to `POST /messages` with `Authorization: Bearer <token>` to post messages to the chat.
- Tokens expire after some hours.

The crux is that a `POST /auth` request resets any previous token and invalidates all other clients which hold tokens. There is no `GET /auth` or similar to get existing tokens.

This now becomes a coordination problem between concurrent instances of randomly spawned bots. They all need to use the same token, but will generate tokens independently. I'm not terribly keen on introducing some singleton service whose task it would be to only coordinate the token, I'd like to keep the independently-scaling Lambda paradigm. I'm using DynamoDB to store tokens to try to coordinate them between bot instances, but still have edge case race conditions which can require up to three retries to get tokens settled.

The worst case is an invalid token stored in DynamoDB and two bots being instantiated simultaneously:

- both will read the invalid token
- both will attempt requests which fail
- both will try to read the token again, since another bot may have refreshed it in the meantime
- both will discard the token which is known to be bad
- both will generate a new token and store it, one of them randomly "winning"
- the "loser" will be doing another bad request and repeat the previous steps

Ideally there would be a lockable resource which one bot can lock and generate a token, and others can wait for. But AFAIK DynamoDB doesn't have that kind of functionality.

What is a good pattern and/or AWS service to coordinate such a singleton token between independent, parallel Lambda instances?

Comment: what about a single instance redis(ElastiCache) and controlling it with LUA(atomic). Being single instance there won't be racing condition(no cap theorem no eventual consistency), with redis's single threaded architecture only `one and only request at a time` - , with lua it is going to be atomic (even you have multiple commands running consecutively)

Comment: I haven't looked at redis/ElastiCache in particular yet. It looks like this might work: https://redis.io/topics/distlock? However, ElastiCache seems to cost at least ~$20/m, while DynamoDB is virtually free for the demand I'm putting on it for this project. I'll certainly look into it more as alternative, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to offer a slightly different take on the @Jens' answer:

1. **Use DynamoDB to store the current auth token**: A DDB table with a single entry can be used as an authoritative source for the auth token. More on how to update the tokens at #3 below.
2. **Local caching for the auth token**: While Lambda is supposed to be stateless, it does actually have the ability to do [some local caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html), so each Lambda instance should follow some logic like this:

   - if it has a NULL value for the auth token in the local cache, read it from DDB and update the local cache
   - if it has a non-NULL value for the auth token, then attempt to use the auth token to make requests
   - if a request fails due to invalidated token, attempt to do a token refresh (see #3 below)
3. **Take advantage of conditional writes to refresh tokens**:  For this, any lambda instance that finds a bad token should attempt to "designate itself" to refresh the token by doing a [conditional write](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) on the token record in the DDB table, attempting to claim itself as the self-designated updater

   - if the conditional write succeeds, the lambda continues to make the
     `POST /auth` request, get a new token and subsequently update the
     DDB record and removes itself from the lock;
   - if the conditional write fails, the lambda should back-off for some time (maybe 200 ms or so) and then attempt to re-read the record to see if another lambda successfully refreshed the token in the mean time
   - if upon reading the record the lambda determines that the token had been refreshed (ie. token value is different than what it had), it can proceed to using the new token and all is good; if it find that the record is still locked, it can wait some more and retry
   - you should probably come up with a safe back-off period of time (say 1-2 seconds) after which a lambda should "take over" the responsibility of updating the token, under the assumption that the other instance that had previously locked it has been terminated for whatever reason; this was you don't end up in a deadlock where all instances wait forever

---

This solution has the advantage of reducing the need to read from DDB for each request and not requiring any other services (other the Lambda and DDB).

When performing the conditional write, lambda can generate a UUID for the operation and store this UUID and a timestamp on the items to indicate the time when the item was "locked". Subsequent instances will read the UUID and timestamp and determine that some other instance must be working on the item. And if too much time has passed since the item was locked, another instance can "take over".

Comment: That's basically the distributed-lock mechanism described by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65181056/476). I'm currently experimenting with [dynamo-dlm](https://pypi.org/project/dynamo-dlm/) for that, but of course, rolling this into the token record itself without a separate table would also do. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help — it’d be interesting to know, if you end up doing something like this, how it performs for you

Comment: I've [outlined my implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65202299/476). So far it's passed light testing and I'm pretty happy with it. Works without additional dependencies and minimal API retries.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would try to de-couple read and write operations of the token. There should only be one "process" that writes tokens and multiple "processes" that read the token from your storage.

One solution could be for example, that you use AWS EventBridge to periodically trigger a Lambda (say every 30 minutes). This Lambda calls the `/auth` endpoint, gets a fresh token and then stores it in DynamoDB.

The Lambdas with the business logic then should use consistent/strong reads to avoid race conditions (writing a new token while another Lambda reads a now stale token).

The business logic in your message Lambda just has to read the token from the database now, allowing you to "scale" to as many Lambdas as you want without them getting in each others way.

Comment: That's also an acceptable approach, though you could get into trouble if the stored token is invalidated by whatever other means, and now the bots are stranded without a valid token and no way to generate a new one by themselves…

Comment: @deceze That is true, but was not mentioned in your original post that the token could be invalidated at any time. All of the possible solutions that come to mind have some kind of caveat.

Another solution I was pondering was mounting an [EFS volume to all your Lambdas](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/) and just use a local file cache with a lock file. I bet that there are a lot of solutions out there for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

While there is no native locking implemented in DynamoDB, here is a 2017 AWS blog post showcasing DynamoDB locking lib for Java SDK.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/

This excerpt shines some light on the mechanism:

> The DynamoDB Lock Client uses the DynamoDB UpdateItem API to heartbeat
> and extend locks each host owns. Additionally, the lock client uses
> client-side TTL to expire locks. The lock client uses a recent version
> of the AWS SDK for Java. The locking protocol employs conditional
> updates extensively and throughout the lifecycle of a lock (creation,
> renewal by heartbeat, and expiration by deletion).

There are some forks and adaptations for other languages like Python.

Comment: The problem is precisely with *concurrency*. Within one Lambda instance I'm already doing singleton storage. The issue is when multiple Lambda instances are spun up concurrently.

Comment: @deceze then have you considered using TTL mechanism of DynamoDB and using same storage across the environments like I described? You can also add a strongly consistent read request to the table when requesting token value to try and mitigate possible race conditions.

Comment: I'm not sure how TTL would help here exactly. And yes, I am using strongly consistent reads, but that still doesn't protect against the sort of race conditions you get with simultaneously launching Lambda instances.

Comment: If you run into issues like these even with strong reads then maybe dynamodb lock library can help? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/building-distributed-locks-with-the-dynamodb-lock-client/ it's an obscure bit and maybe not available for other languages

Comment: This actually looks promising, a locking protocol specific to DynamoDB. If you update your answer around that, perhaps with a high level overview of how the protocol works, that would be an accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will be using this in Python and I've found https://pypi.org/project/dynamo-dlm/, which seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing this with a distributed-lock algorithm, hinging on DynamoDB's conditional writes, as largely outlined in [Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65192951/476) and [Oleksii's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65181056/476). I'll provide some of the details below (implemented in [Python's boto3 API](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#table), omitting a number of implementation-specific details):

1. Read the token from DynamoDB and store it locally.
2. If a request made using a token is being rejected, mark the token as "invalid" internally.
3. If no token exists or it is known to be invalid, follow this procedure:

   ```py
   if old_token:
       condition = Attr('AccessToken').eq(old_token)
   else:
       condition = Attr('AccessToken').not_exists()

   release_code = uuid4().hex
   now = int(time())
   lock = {'release_code': release_code, 'expires': now + 15}
   condition &= Attr('AccessTokenUpdateLock').not_exists() | Attr('AccessTokenUpdateLock.expires').lte(now)

   table.update_item(
       Key=key,
       UpdateExpression='SET AccessTokenUpdateLock = :l',
       ExpressionAttributeValues={':l': lock},
       ConditionExpression=condition,
       ReturnValues='ALL_NEW'
   )
   ```

   In a nutshell, this adds an `AccessTokenUpdateLock` property to the specific bot's record in the table, *if* no such lock already exists or it has already expired. The lock as such is basically a random string. If this succeeds, it is safe to request a new token from the API. Otherwise this will fail with a `DynamoDB.Client.exceptions.ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

   In the latter case, the client goes into a exponentially backing-off read loop:

   ```py
   @backoff.on_predicate(backoff.expo, jitter=backoff.full_jitter, max_value=10, max_time=60)
   def await_updated_access_token():
       item = table.get_item(Key=key, ConsistentRead=True)

       if item['Item'].get('AccessToken') != old_token:
           # store new token
           return # new token

       try:
           if item['Item']['AccessTokenUpdateLock']['expires'] <= time():
               raise AccessTokenUpdateHasFailed
       except KeyError:
           return None
   ```

   The [`backoff` library](https://pypi.org/project/backoff/) will keep repeating this until the function returns a token or raises an exception. If `AccessTokenUpdateHasFailed` is raised, it starts again and tries to acquire a lock itself.

   If the client *did* successfully acquire a lock, it then fetches a new API token, and writes it to DynamoDB:

   ```py
   if old_token:
       condition = Attr('AccessToken').eq(old_token)
   else:
       condition = Attr('AccessToken').not_exists()

   condition &= Attr('AccessTokenUpdateLock.release_code').eq(release_code)

   response = table.update_item(
       Key=key,
       UpdateExpression='SET AccessToken = :t REMOVE AccessTokenUpdateLock',
       ExpressionAttributeValues={':t': new_token},
       ConditionExpression=condition,
       ReturnValues='ALL_NEW'
   )
   ```

This appears to be reasonably robust with minimal retries to the API itself.

Comment: looks good - make sure the expiration timeout you set on the lock is reasonably configured based on the API you use for auth: 15 seconds is a lot; the other thing to watch for is the configured timeout on the lambda itself (must be longer than the expiration you set). Hopefully the p99 latency of the auth api you’re using is in the hundreds of milliseconds so an expiration of 2 seconds would make more sense?!

Comment: Yeah, still gathering real world data for that API, 15 seconds is *very* conservative indeed. I’ll tweak that over time.